# How to install a beamer theme in Lyx

Tags: beamer, lyx, installing

I would like to use [the Wuerzburg Beamer Theme](http://latex-my.blogspot.gr/2011/06/wuerburg-beamer-theme.html) for my thesis presentation but i dont know how to install it in Lyx.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Follow the link [wuerzburg](http://www.cgogolin.de/Computer.html) on the page you are referring to above
2. download the three `.sty` files at the bottom of the post dated 2009-01-21 to the folder where your thesis `.lyx` file is located
3. Open your thesis `.lyx` file and go to *< Document | Settings | LaTeX Preamble >*
4. Replace the beamer theme references there with

   `\useoutertheme{wuerzburg}`

   `\useinnertheme[outline]{chamfered}`

   `\usecolortheme{shark}`

and you should be done

Answer (score 1):

Changing a theme for presentation in LyX is easy.

1. Just go to `Document > Settings`
2. Select LaTeX preamble and
3. write `\usetheme{ThemeName}`, where `ThemeName` can be changed to the name of the theme like `Warsaw` etc.

Check out this video. It will show you how to change the Theme in LyX:
[Changing Theme for Presentation in LyX](https://youtu.be/OYwhuvogfPY?list=PLJn3oPuoFR0d1HHf5hhrMjFLlJQMF9yXg)